# cUrl request every 2 seconds and echo results

Tags: php, ajax, function, curl

i want send cUrl variable to function every 2 seconds, and show the results in the page.
i'm wand using Ajax, but how i'm send cUrl details with the functions parameters?

Thank's for helpers, and have good day :)

Answer (score 0):

you can call your ajax function in every two second like this uning `setInteval` function of js

```
setInterval(your_ajax_function,2000); // call your_ajax_function in every 2 seconds

function your_ajax_function()
{
    // ajax function statements here
    // and send request to the php file
    // get output from php file as response
    // show response in your desired div
}
```

Now in php file you can call you curl function etc and put the output as echo

Comment: But, i'm need Replay the php functions every 2 seconds.
how i'm send php cUrl requests with ajax?

Answer (score 0):

CURL with PhP is still server based as all PhP code is. The only way I myself can think of sending your request every 2 seconds would be forcing a refresh every 2 seconds of page in question.

```
    $requiredPage = "example.com";
    header('Refresh:2;url='.$requiredPage);
```